How do MsgBoxes and GUIs work in autohotkey v2
ok so I have this code
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

global MyGui := ""
global uNID := "", Password := ""
global EditUsername := "", EditPassword := ""
global CurrentDay := A_DD
global Oct31MessageShown := false
global SavesFilePath := A_ScriptDir . "\\julia present\\Julias present saves"

^END::Reload
^+END::ExitApp
^!T::MsgBox("Test hotkey works!")

^+U:: {
Run("https://go.utah.edu/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fincommon2.sso.utah.edu%2Fidp%2FAuthn%2FExternal%3Fconversation%3De1s1&entityId=http%3A%2F%2Futah.instructure.com%2Fsaml2")

    ; Wait for the page to load (adjust the sleep time if needed)
    Sleep(1000)
    
    ; Read the saved credentials
    savedUNID := ReadSavedCredential("uNID")
    savedPassword := ReadSavedCredential("Password")
    
    ; Ensure the window is active
    if WinExist("A")
        WinActivate
    
    ; Paste the username
    if (savedUNID != "") {
        SendInput(savedUNID)
        Sleep(100)  ; Increased delay before tabbing to next field
        SendInput("{Tab}")
    }
    
    ; Paste the password
    if (savedPassword != "") {
        Sleep(100)  ; Increased delay before pasting password
        SendInput(savedPassword)
        Sleep(100)  ; Increased delay before pressing Enter
        SendInput("{Enter}")
    }

}

^+!U:: {
global MyGui, uNID, Password, EditUsername, EditPassword

    MyGui := Gui()
    MyGui.Add("Text",, "Please enter your U of U ID:")
    EditUsername := MyGui.Add("Edit", "vuNID w200")
    MyGui.Add("Text",, "Please enter your U of U Password:")
    EditPassword := MyGui.Add("Edit", "vPassword w200 Password")
    SubmitButton := MyGui.Add("Button", "w100", "Submit").OnEvent("Click", ButtonSubmit)
    
    ; Create a hotkey that's only active when the GUI is open
    HotIfWinactive("ahk_class AutoHotkeyGUI")
    Hotkey("Enter", HandleEnter)
    
    MyGui.Show()

}

ButtonSubmit(\*) {
; Retrieve the values from the GUI controls
savedUNID := EditUsername.Text
savedPassword := EditPassword.Text

    ; Close the GUI
    MyGui.Destroy()
    
    ; Save the credentials to file
    SaveCredentials(savedUNID, savedPassword)
    
    ; Display the entered information
    MsgBox("Credentials saved successfully!`nuNID: " . savedUNID . "`nPassword: " . savedPassword)
    
    ; Update global variables
    global uNID := savedUNID
    global Password := savedPassword

}

; Function to handle Enter key press
HandleEnter(\*) {
if (MyGui.FocusedCtrl = EditUsername) {
EditPassword.Focus()
} else if (MyGui.FocusedCtrl = EditPassword) {
ButtonSubmit()
}
}

; Function to save credentials to the file
SaveCredentials(uNID, Password) {
try {
; Clear the file by opening it in write mode (which truncates the file)
fileObj := FileOpen(SavesFilePath, "w")
if (fileObj) {
; Write the new credentials
fileObj.Write("uNID:" . uNID . "\`n")
fileObj.Write("Password:" . Password)
fileObj.Close()
} else {
throw Error("Unable to open file for writing")
}
} catch as err {
MsgBox("Error saving credentials: " . err.Message)
}
}

; Function to read a specific credential from the file
ReadSavedCredential(credentialType) {
try {
fileContent := FileRead(SavesFilePath)
lines := StrSplit(fileContent, "\`n")
for line in lines {
if (InStr(line, credentialType . ":") == 1) {
return StrSplit(line, ":")\[2\]
}
}
} catch as err {
MsgBox("Error reading credentials: " . err.Message)
}
return ""
}

UpdateCurrentDay() {
global CurrentDay, Oct31MessageShown
newDay := A_DD
MsgBox("current day" . CurrentDay . "newDay" . newDay)
if (newDay != CurrentDay) {
CurrentDay := newDay

        ; Reset the flag if it's a new day
        Oct31MessageShown := false
        
        ; Check if it's October 31st, 2024
        if (A_MM = "9" and A_DD = "4" and !Oct31MessageShown) {
            SoundBeep
            MsgBox("About to call OpenSpecialWindow")
            OpenSpecialWindow()
            Oct31MessageShown := true
        }
    }

}

OpenSpecialWindow() {
MsgBox("OpenSpecialWindow function called")

    specialGui := Gui()
    specialGui.Add("Text",, "Happy Birthday Julia, and Happy Halloween")
    specialGui.Add("Text",, "This is a special message for October 31st")
    specialGui.Add("Button", "w100", "Close").OnEvent("Click", (*) => specialGui.Destroy())
    
    specialGui.Show()
    
    MsgBox("GUI should be visible now")

}

SetTimer(UpdateCurrentDay, 60000)
UpdateCurrentDay()

for some reason the only GUI and Msgboxes that shows up are in ^+U and ^+!U function.
Why do those functions work but not ^!T::(MsgBox("Test hotkey works"))
I've tried adding Msgboxes basically everywhere and they only ever open in those functions. I even tried having that outside of a function and that didn't show up when then project was loading.

Lines 63, 84 and 117. Here is working the msgbox with ^!T
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

global MyGui := ""
global uNID := "", Password := ""
global EditUsername := "", EditPassword := ""
global CurrentDay := A_DD
global Oct31MessageShown := false
global SavesFilePath := A_ScriptDir . "\\julia present\\Julias present saves"

^END::Reload
^+END::ExitApp
^!T::MsgBox("Test hotkey works!")

^+U:: {
Run("https://go.utah.edu/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fincommon2.sso.utah.edu%2Fidp%2FAuthn%2FExternal%3Fconversation%3De1s1&entityId=http%3A%2F%2Futah.instructure.com%2Fsaml2")

    ; Wait for the page to load (adjust the sleep time if needed)
    Sleep(1000)
    
    ; Read the saved credentials
    savedUNID := ReadSavedCredential("uNID")
    savedPassword := ReadSavedCredential("Password")
    
    ; Ensure the window is active
    if WinExist("A")
        WinActivate
    
    ; Paste the username
    if (savedUNID != "") {
        SendInput(savedUNID)
        Sleep(100)  ; Increased delay before tabbing to next field
        SendInput("{Tab}")
    }
    
    ; Paste the password
    if (savedPassword != "") {
        Sleep(100)  ; Increased delay before pasting password
        SendInput(savedPassword)
        Sleep(100)  ; Increased delay before pressing Enter
        SendInput("{Enter}")
    }

}

^+!U:: {
global MyGui, uNID, Password, EditUsername, EditPassword

    MyGui := Gui()
    MyGui.Add("Text",, "Please enter your U of U ID:")
    EditUsername := MyGui.Add("Edit", "vuNID w200")
    MyGui.Add("Text",, "Please enter your U of U Password:")
    EditPassword := MyGui.Add("Edit", "vPassword w200 Password")
    SubmitButton := MyGui.Add("Button", "w100", "Submit").OnEvent("Click", ButtonSubmit)
    
    ; Create a hotkey that's only active when the GUI is open
    HotIfWinactive("ahk_class AutoHotkeyGUI")
    Hotkey("Enter", HandleEnter)
    
    MyGui.Show()

}

ButtonSubmit(*) {   ;   REMOVED unnecessary "\"
; Retrieve the values from the GUI controls
savedUNID := EditUsername.Text
savedPassword := EditPassword.Text

    ; Close the GUI
    MyGui.Destroy()
    
    ; Save the credentials to file
    SaveCredentials(savedUNID, savedPassword)
    
    ; Display the entered information
    MsgBox("Credentials saved successfully!`nuNID: " . savedUNID . "`nPassword: " . savedPassword)
    
    ; Update global variables
    global uNID := savedUNID
    global Password := savedPassword

}

; Function to handle Enter key press
HandleEnter(*) {    ;   REMOVED unnecessary "\"
if (MyGui.FocusedCtrl = EditUsername) {
EditPassword.Focus()
} else if (MyGui.FocusedCtrl = EditPassword) {
ButtonSubmit()
}
}

; Function to save credentials to the file
SaveCredentials(uNID, Password) {
try {
; Clear the file by opening it in write mode (which truncates the file)
fileObj := FileOpen(SavesFilePath, "w")
if (fileObj) {
; Write the new credentials
fileObj.Write("uNID:" . uNID . "\`n")
fileObj.Write("Password:" . Password)
fileObj.Close()
} else {
throw Error("Unable to open file for writing")
}
} catch as err {
MsgBox("Error saving credentials: " . err.Message)
}
}

; Function to read a specific credential from the file
ReadSavedCredential(credentialType) {
try {
fileContent := FileRead(SavesFilePath)
lines := StrSplit(fileContent, "\`n")
for line in lines {
if (InStr(line, credentialType . ":") == 1) {
return StrSplit(line, ":")[2]   ;   REMOVED unnecessary "\"
}
}
} catch as err {
MsgBox("Error reading credentials: " . err.Message)
}
return ""
}

UpdateCurrentDay() {
global CurrentDay, Oct31MessageShown
newDay := A_DD
MsgBox("current day" . CurrentDay . "newDay" . newDay)
if (newDay != CurrentDay) {
CurrentDay := newDay

        ; Reset the flag if it's a new day
        Oct31MessageShown := false
        
        ; Check if it's October 31st, 2024
        if (A_MM = "9" and A_DD = "4" and !Oct31MessageShown) {
            SoundBeep
            MsgBox("About to call OpenSpecialWindow")
            OpenSpecialWindow()
            Oct31MessageShown := true
        }
    }

}

OpenSpecialWindow() {
    MsgBox("OpenSpecialWindow function called")
    
        specialGui := Gui()
        specialGui.Add("Text",, "Happy Birthday Julia, and Happy Halloween")
        specialGui.Add("Text",, "This is a special message for October 31st")
        specialGui.Add("Button", "w100", "Close").OnEvent("Click", (*) => specialGui.Destroy())
        
        specialGui.Show()
        
        MsgBox("GUI should be visible now")
    
    }
    
    SetTimer(UpdateCurrentDay, 60000)
    UpdateCurrentDay()

